# Find the probability distribution based on half-Gaussian and Rayleigh

Tags: probability-distributions

**Problem**

Suppose random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ has a half-Gaussian distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$, $Y$ has a Rayleigh distribution with unknown $b$. Then what is the distribution of $Z=XY$

**What I have Done**

This question seems to be pretty straightforward but I got stuck halfway.

Obviously $f_X(x)=\frac{2}{{\sqrt{2 \pi}}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\ (x>0)$ and $f_Y(y)=\frac{y^2}{b^2}\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2})$. Then
$$
f_Z(z)=f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=\frac{2y^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}b^2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{y^2}{b^2}+x^2))
$$

I got stuck right here. I do not know what to do next since it seems that I could not transform the form with both $x$ and $y$ into the one with merely $z$.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in general not true that $f_Z(z) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) $ for $Z=XY$ **even** if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Let $F(\cdot) $ denote the CDF of a random variable. We first write down the CDF of $Z$. Let $z\geq 0$:
\begin{align} 
F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z) = P\left(  XY\leq z\right) = \int^\infty_0P(X\leq z/y) f_Y(y)  dy
\end{align} 
Differentiating under the integral sign yields:
\begin{align} 
f_Z(z) = \int^\infty_0\frac{1} {y} f_X(z/y) f_Y(y)  dy
\end{align} 
So you have the CDF of $Z$. I don't know if that can be found exactly. I'll leave the calculations for you.